# Does not return value from loop

Tags: c#, loops, methods, return

So if I make a method that is supposed to return values it does not. I know i could easily do it with void but can anyone explain why the loop does not return the value here is a simple example.

```
public static int EvenNumberGenerator(int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= y; x++)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        return x;
    }
}
```

I also tried it by moving the **continue** part and just incrementing it with two but it still would say not all paths return the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it still would say not all paths return the value

It says that because what will happen if `y<0`? Loop is not run and there is no `return` statement executed.

Also in your case if `y>=0` it will return (0) immediately, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you slightly misunderstand the problem.

The issue isn't that the loop doesn't exit, it's that the loop is never entered.

As Giorgi said, imagine a value of Y that already meets the exit case (x <= y) - in that instance the for-loop will never be entered.

Comment: Sorry i completely forgot about that. Thank you though!